# matplotlib line chart add subgroup X axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to add subgroup labels (from the legend) onto the axis of the following graph. I've added my desired outcome below. How do I do that? I'm not sure what to Google... Thanks

#### Plot: Overall Sum - Number of Clicks by Week Number / Year

```
sns.set(style="ticks")
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['week_number'],columns=['month','year'],values=['clicks'],aggfunc=np.sum).plot(kind=('line'),legend=True,title=('Clicks by Week/ Month over Time'),figsize=(15, 8))
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Total Clicks')
plt.xlabel('Week Number, Month')
plt.show();
```

[image]

EDIT: Added data

```
event_id    event_date  week_number holiday month   day year    pub_organization_id clicks  sales   conversion_rate sale_amount_usd pub_commission_usd
0   11  1/1/13  1   New Year's Day  January 1   2013    299 146 1   0.006849    18.00   0.18
1   241 1/1/13  1   New Year's Day  January 1   2013    243 2   1   0.500000    19.90   0.20
2   93  1/1/13  1   New Year's Day  January 1   2013    192 22  1   0.045455    19.95   0.50
3   51  1/1/13  1   New Year's Day  January 1   2013    176 4   1   0.250000    27.00   0.27
4   28  1/1/13  1   New Year's Day  January 1   2013    444 4   1   0.250000    39.95   0.40
```

Comment: Could you please post the data in dataframe you are using?

Comment: Yep, edited above

Comment: can you explain why the [text](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) function is not enough for you?

Comment: Because I would like it to be auto-generated based on the values on the x-axis.

Comment: An automated solution would require to plot dates instead of integer week numbers. Then you may use two different locators for the major and minor ticks, a `WeekdayLocator` and a `MonthLocator` respectively.